# Attempt to index ? ( a new value ) with key 'start'(field'1') in GameGuardian script

Tags: lua

Code:

```
so = gg"getRangesList"[1]["start"] 
py = 17362904 
setvalue(so + py, 4, -476053503) 
py = 17362908 
setvalue(so + py, 4, -516948194) 
py = 20088316 
setvalue(so + py, 4, -476053503) 
py = 20088320 
setvalue(so + py, 4, -516948194) 
py = 21939424 
setvalue(so + py, 4, -476053503) 
py = 21939428 
setvalue(so + py, 4, -516948194) 
gg["toast"](("Hack Map ")) 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
so = gg"getRangesList"[1]["start"]
```

is indexing `gg"getRangesList"[1]` with "start". so `gg"getRangesList"[1]` is a nil value.

That means that the table returned by `gg"getRangesList"` does not have a value for at index `1`.

To fix this make sure that the value exists befor you index it.